# loadfile() and dostring() don't work from inside run(wsapi_env)

Tags: lua

I try to run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wsapi.cgi

require("lib/request")  -- wsapi lib
require("lib/response")
require("io")
module("loadHtml", package.seeall)

---This function generates a response for the WSAPI calls that need to GET a file
function run(wsapi_env)
    --check the request
    local req = wsapi.request.new(wsapi_env or {})
    --generate response
    res = wsapi.response.new()
    ---a couple of utility functions that will be used to write something to response
    function print(str) res:write(str) end
    function println(str) res:write(str) res:write('<br/>') end

    println("running...")
    ff=dofile("index.html.lua")
    println("done!")

    return res:finish()
end

return _M
```

And the "index.html.lua" looks something like this:

```
print([[<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world!
</html>]])
```

it runs without error but all I get in the client side is exactly this:

```
running...<br/>done!<br/>
```

In other words, the println() in the run() function works, but it doesn't work inside the "index.html.lua". I tried loadfile() instead of dofile() and it's the same. The funny thing is that I wrote a test code and it works:

```
--tryDoFileRun.lua:
function e()
    function p(str)
        print(str)
    end
    dofile("tryDoFile.lua")
end
e()
```

which runs this:

```
--tryDoFile.lua
print("in tryDoFile.lua")
p("calling p")
```

and the output is:

```
in tryDoFile.lua
calling p
```

Just as it should be. however, this same idea doesn't work in the first code above.
How can I get this code to let the index.html.lua use my print() function?

System spec: WSAPI, Lighttpd server, LUA 5.1, ARM9, Linux 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `module` call. It replaces the environment of the current chunk, but `dofile` doesn't inherit the modified environment. The solution is either writing directly to the global environment:

```
_G.print = function(str) res:write(str) end
```

Or modifying the environment of the loaded chunk of code:

```
function print(str) res:write(str) end
ff = loadfile("index.html.lua")
getfenv(ff).print = print
ff()
```

The latter can be wrapped in a convenient HTML template loading function.